# Combinations/Permutations of 8 rooks on a chess board

Tags: probability

Rooks (or castles) are chess pieces that are only allowed to move horizontally or vertically
on a chessboard. The following question on rook placements on a standard
chessboard assumes that rooks must be placed on one of the 64 allowed positions on
the board, and no two rooks can share the same position.
How many different ways are there of placing 8 indistinguishable rooks on a standard
8 × 8 chessboard if there are no restrictions on their placement, other than those stated above?

The answer that I believe to be right is 64!/(56!)(8!). My reasoning for this is that there are 64! possibilities and then you have to divide out by the 56 empty squares as well as the 8 squares the rooks are placed on. Is my logic/answer correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why rooks? I mean, aren't you just asking in how many ways can we choose $8$ squares from $64$?

Comment: Which is indeed $64!\big/(8!\; 56!)$

Comment: Usually, since rooks have been mentioned, this question comes with another condition, such as "none of the pieces are attacking each other." Do you mean to include such a condition here?